# Name for permutations that have to follow a certain order?

Tags: permutations

Is there a name for permutations that have to follow a certain order?

For example, suppose `ABC` is a set of characters, and you are trying to figure out all the possible permutations, except, in every instance, A must be ordered before B. So that`ABC`
`ACB`
`CAB` are valid, while something like `BAC` would be invalid.

Comment: I’m not sure if there is a name for it as permutations, but it can be seen as “linear extensions of partially ordered sets.” In your case, the partial order has $A\leq A,B\leq B, C\leq C,$ and $A\leq B.$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set

Comment: Would that be the permutation, divided by the permutations of the relevant elements?  I think it is just a quotient of permutations.

Comment: It’s definitely a subset of permutations, not a quotient, as groups. @RobertTheTutor

Comment: Another link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension

Comment: True, I was thinking of counting the permutations rather than listing them.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is there a formula for listing or counting partially ordered sets? Essentially treating them like permutations with some constraints?